# Dismissing 2 ViewController consecutively

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I try 2 ways to dismissed 2 viewcontrollers consecutively but only one of them got dismissed not the second one

method1

```
-(void) LoginDone:(NSNotification *)notif 
 {
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];   //previous viewcontroller
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];   //current viewcontroller
  }
```

method2

```
-(void) LoginDone:(NSNotification *)notif 
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoginDone2" object:nil];

 }

-(void) LoginDone2:(NSNotification *)notif 
{
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


 }
```

I need to find out a way to dismiss both the previous viewcontroller and current viewcontroller consecutively.

Answer (score 8):

This is now an old question, but it seems to be exactly the problem I am having presently.
Here what I did:

```
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController
     dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And it works for me. I hope it can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 5):

By calling

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

you are telling `self` to dismiss the view it presented. Telling twice the same `self` object to dismiss the view it presented, will not change the result. In other words `self` cannot represent the "current view" and the "previous view" at the same time as per your comment to the code. `self` is just a single controller representing a single view, either the current or the previous one.

To fix this, you should send the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to `self` (that presented the top-most view, I assume) *and* to the *other* view controller object that presented the previous view.

In other words, I would expect something like this:

```
-(void) LoginDone:(NSNotification *)notif 
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   [self.previousController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Actually, you could send just one message to the second view controller and both views would be dismissed ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)):

> If you present several view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but maybe somebody will look for solution on this issue so here it is:

```
-(void) closeModalViews 
{
    [previousVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but first you must dismiss the current view controller's view and only then can you dismiss the presenting view controller's view.

Answer (score 1):

I like JPetric's idea, but first you must dismiss the current view controller's view and only then can you dismiss the presenting view controller's view.

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(void) {
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand you are trying something like below:

> 1. There are 2 view controllers.
> 2. You want both of them to be vanished.
> 3. Another controller comes in.

But the fact is only one controller is displayed, why you would need to dismiss 2 then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use self.view.hidden=true; on the jumped viewcontrollers while animating back to the first viewcontroller. Using [self.presentingViewController dismiss...] is not working for me without hiding.