# delegation issue with dismissing multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, modalviewcontroller

I asked a question about dismissing multiple view controllers previously and the answers that i was given along with the possible solutions i found elsewhere have all failed to achieve the desired effect. i have narrowed down my issue to something with the way i set up my delegation. the code is below and i would really appreciate any feedback.

my full project can be downloaded here:  https://www.yousendit.com/download/TEhWckhYQVNYSHpIRHNUQw

Thanks.

```
//
//  QuestionViewController.h
//  learningTheRopes1
//
//  Created by James Ulle on 7/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Question.h"
#import "AnswerViewController.h"

@interface QuestionViewController : UIViewController <AnswerViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *currentQuestionDisplay;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userAnswerTextField;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Question *currentQuestion;

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender;

- (void)dismissQVC;

@end

    //
    //  QuestionViewController.m
    //  learningTheRopes1
    //
    //  Created by James Ulle on 7/18/12.
    //  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "QuestionViewController.h"

    @interface QuestionViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation QuestionViewController

    @synthesize currentQuestionDisplay;
    @synthesize userAnswerTextField;
    @synthesize currentQuestion;

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        AnswerViewController *avc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [avc setCurrentQuestion:currentQuestion];
        [avc setUserAnswer:[userAnswerTextField text]];
    }

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.currentQuestionDisplay setText:[currentQuestion question]];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setCurrentQuestionDisplay:nil];
    [self setUserAnswerTextField:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [userAnswerTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)dismissQVC {
    NSLog(@"Dismiss QVC");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

@end

    //
//  AnswerViewController.h
//  learningTheRopes1
//
//  Created by James Ulle on 7/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Question.h"

@protocol AnswerViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)dismissQVC;
@end

#import "QuestionViewController.h"

@interface AnswerViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *displayCurrentAnswer;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Question *currentQuestion;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userAnswer;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AnswerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)dismissAnswerVC:(id)sender;

@end

    //
//  AnswerViewController.m
//  learningTheRopes1
//
//  Created by James Ulle on 7/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AnswerViewController.h"

@interface AnswerViewController ()

@end

@implementation AnswerViewController

@synthesize displayCurrentAnswer;
@synthesize currentQuestion;
@synthesize userAnswer;
@synthesize delegate;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([userAnswer isEqualToString:currentQuestion.answer]) {
        [self.displayCurrentAnswer setText:@"You are correct!"];
    }
    else {
        [self.displayCurrentAnswer setText:@"You are wrong!"];
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setDisplayCurrentAnswer:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)dismissAnswerVC:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        NSLog(@"Dismiss AVC");
        [[self delegate] dismissQVC];

    }];

}

@end
```

and finally my output is this (which shows that the completion block in indeed called, but the delegate call back to dimissQVC does not happen:

```
2012-08-03 19:04:34.235
learningTheRopes1[4165:f803] Dismiss AVC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the prepareForSegue method, you missed this line:

avc.delegate = self;

Comment: thanks you. thank you. thank you. 
I am new to iOS and delegation had me stumped. works exactly like i wanted it to now.